# Vue CLI - Environment Specific URL's

Tags: vue.js, webpack

Working on moving a project to Vue and separating our API from the UI. It's been going well, but the only issue I have is the URL's for the UI won't match the API service so I can't use relative paths, and I'm unsure how to get webpack to switch them out for absolute paths that will match the appropriate service.

Ideally I'd like a webpack.config.js variable that when it packs the js knows to replace something like '%API_URL%' with some value. Is there a way with webpack or the vue CLI to handle this situation?

Answer (score 0):

According to [Vue CLI's guide](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#environment-variables), you can define environment variables:

> You can specify env variables by placing the following files in your project root:

```
.env                # loaded in all cases
.env.local          # loaded in all cases, ignored by git
.env.[mode]         # only loaded in specified mode
.env.[mode].local   # only loaded in specified mode, ignored by git
```

> An env file simply contains key=value pairs of environment variables:

```
FOO=bar
VUE_APP_SECRET=secret
```

> Note that only variables that start with `VUE_APP_` will be statically embedded into the client bundle with `webpack.DefinePlugin`.
>
> You then can access env variables in your application code:

```
console.log(process.env.VUE_APP_SECRET)
```

Comment: process.env.VUE_APP_SECRET won't exist on my frontend code. I can get the config in the proper environment, i just don't know how to switch it out in all myfrontend javascript files.

Comment: You can switch your env by launching `npm run serve -- --mode production` for example and it will use the variables from `.env.production`.